# In first step of Ubuntu installation: crash screen

Tags: installation, 13.10, screen, 32-bit, crash

I am a Java programmer and I want to install Ubuntu 13.10 to use for my programming needs. But I have a problem. On my first step of installing Ubuntu X86 (I am a newbie)
when I go to setup screen in boot, the screen will crash:

[image: Crash screen]

But on another PC this works fine.

- Monitor: CRT 17-inch (Might this be the problem?)
- CPU: Intel dual E2200 2.2 X86
- RAM: 2gb
- Graphics Card: Nvidia 9500GT